# Capture that a listener dismissed the MetaMask popup

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I'm using ethers.js and I'm writing code to connect to MetaMask when the user clicks a "connect" button on my site.

The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to determine if the user dismisses the MetaMask popup.

I've tried multiple variations of code that includes using async/await and promises, I've tried using ethers.js, and I've tried using MetaMask directly. I've tried wrapping my code with a try/catch block and I've tried using .catch().

It's almost as if the request never resolves.

It would be ideal if I could avoid using the MetaMask specific API and instead rely on ethers to provide whatever the most standard Ethereum interface is.

UPDATE: After some additional testing I can confirm that calling

`await ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});`

only throws if the listener dismisses a request to **connect**. However, the resulting promise appears to remain unresolved if the listener was not already authenticated and therefore dismisses the popup that asks for a password.

Comment: You could alternatively display a UI modal whenever no web3 instance is detected.

Comment: in my case the ethereum instance is detected, it's just requesting that the user re-enter their password.

Comment: Open the browser console and see if you get any logged error when you dismiss the modal. If you get one, you could catch it in the UI code.

Comment: This may be a bug in MetaMask, I've filed a ticket: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/11280